# Why the number of headers and blocks are different?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoind, blockchain.info-api

When I run `$bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo` it shows me:

```
{
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 20204,
  "headers": 563653,
  ....
}
```

But if a block is identified by his header, the numbers of headers and block must be the same, what I didn't understand?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Bitcoin RPC Documentation - getblockchaininfo](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/blockchain/getblockchaininfo/)

```
"blocks": xxxxxx,             (numeric) the current number of blocks processed in the server
"headers": xxxxxx,            (numeric) the current number of headers we have validated
```

`blocks` is the height of the highest downloaded and validated block, and `headers` is the height of the highest validated block header (minus one on both, since counting starts from zero). Validating a header by itself doesn't require the entire block.